# How to select an attribute from all xml elements on the same level with sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My xml is:

```xml
<foo>
    <bar>
        <button text="a"/>
        <button text="b"/>
        <button text="c"/>
    </bar>
</foo>
```

With the following I'm able to get one of those text values, but I'm trying to get all 3 back (each on their own row). I realize `[1]` is why I'm getting one back... but I'm not sure how to get all of them back?

```sql
select 
    cast(f.xml as xml).value('(/foo/bar/button/@text)[1]', 'varchar(max)') as foo
from
    (select top 1 * from files) f
```

This returns

```
Foo
---
 a
```

Where I'm actually trying to get

```
Foo
---
 a
 b
 c
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `nodes` operator in your `FROM`, which you can do by using a `CROSS APPLY`:

```
DECLARE @XML xml = '
<foo>
    <bar>
        <button text="a"/>
        <button text="b"/>
        <button text="c"/>
    </bar>
</foo>';

SELECT fb.button.value('@text','char(1)')
FROM (VALUES(@XML))X(XMLString)
     CROSS APPLY X.XMLSTRING.nodes('foo/bar/button') fb(button);
```

Comment: This is perfect, thank you. If I wanted to have multiple columns on the result, each representing a different attribute/path in the xml, I tried removing the `/button` from the `nodes()` and moving it up to the `fb.button.value(''/button/@text')' but to no avail

Comment: Difficult to give a further answer without an example; but siggests you don't understand how this works if you didn't get the required results, perhaps?

Comment: Nevermind, I can just add new columns to the top level select with different attribute selectors.

Answer (score 1):

I think this query does the trick:

```
declare @xml as xml = 
'<foo>
    <bar>
        <button text="a"/>
        <button text="b"/>
        <button text="c"/>
    </bar>
</foo>'

select T.C.value('@text','varchar(50)') as button
FROM @xml.nodes('/foo/bar/button') as T(C)
```

[image: output]